# Likelihood function for Gaussian Discriminant Analsis

Tags: machine-learning, generative-model, maximum-likelihood

Im trying to understand how the likelhood function for gaussian discriminant analysis is derived.  I self studying Murphy's Probabilistic Machine learning, and in it, he states the likelihood function as follows:

$P(D|\theta) = \prod_{i=1:n} Cat(y^i|\pi) \prod_{c=1:C} N(x^i | \mu_c, \sum_c)^{I(y^i=c)}$

where $N(x^i | \mu_c, \sum_c)$ is the normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu_c$ which is the mean vector for each feature whose class label is $y^i=c$ and $\sum_c$ is the covariance matrix between the features for the ith example.

Based on my understanding, the way i have been deriving Likelihood is by assuming the following:

We are given the dataset $D = {(x^1, y^1),(x^2, y^2), ..., (x^n, y^n)}$ drawn from unknown distribution $p(X,Y)$.  B/c all pairs are sampled iid, we obtain:

$p(D) = p((x^1, y^1),(x^2, y^2), ..., (x^n, y^n)) = \prod_{i=1:n} p(x^i, y^i | \theta)$

Hence...

$p(D|\theta) = \prod_{i=1:n} p(x^i | y^i = c, \theta)p(y^i=c|\theta)$

Now, i can see the prior is just a categorical distribution given by $Cat(y | \pi)$ so i can see how the Cat function is coming in equation for likelihood since $y^i$ falls in one of C categories.  But what im not able to understand is why is the equation taking product of all clases from $c=1:C$ for the class conditional density?

Is it assuming that for the ith sample, the label can only take on one of c values, hence the distribution of $p(x|y,\theta)$ is given by the product of all the disributions raised to the power of indicator?  hence only one of them can be true?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The indicator function ensures that only the term corresponding to the true class $y_i$ contributes, and all other terms become $1$, effectively ignoring them. This is actually a useful way to  write out the *likelihood function* for mixed continuous–discrete distributions with class-conditional *densities* similar to the [categorical variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution#Formulating_distributions) as mentioned below, so that you can optimize $\pi$ and the $(\mu_c
, Σ_c)$ terms *separately* based on the log-likelihood later on to derive the MLEs for the Gaussians and tied/diagonal covariances.

> Another formulation that appears more complex but facilitates mathematical manipulations is as follows, using the Iverson bracket:
> $${f(x\mid {\boldsymbol {p}})=\prod _{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{[x=i]}},$$
> where ${[x=i]}$ evaluates to $1$ if ${x=i, 0}$ otherwise. There are various advantages of this formulation, e.g.:

> It is easier to write out the likelihood function of a set of independent identically distributed categorical variables.

> It connects the categorical distribution with the related multinomial distribution.

> It shows why the Dirichlet distribution is the conjugate prior of the categorical distribution, and allows the posterior distribution of the parameters to be calculated.